# How to make mouse move between vmware and host without ctrl+alt

Tags: linux, mouse, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have VMware Workstation 15.5 player, and i have a linux machine installed as guest. I recently upgraded it and since then i have to release the mouse by clicking ctrl+alt, where it was moving between guest and host and vise versa without getting locked inside the guest. Is there anyway to move the mouse out of the guest without the ctrl+alt.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by installing:
apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop

reference:
https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/319

Answer (score 0):

Install VMware Tools in the guest machines. That will correct this and let the mouse move freely. I have WMware Workstation here with several guests, all with Tools installed and the mouse will move freely around the screen - then click on what app / machine you want.

Comment: i do have VMware Tools install sorry for not mentioning that. VMware Tools doesn't fix it.

Comment: Try reinstalling the tools. Upgrading a Guest normally requires tools reinstall. See the VMware Menu and there should be a menu item for reinstalling the tools. Do that, restart the guest and check..  Tools (old out of date, or lack of) is the reason for mouse requiring Ctrl Alt to move it

Comment: Thanks John, seems  like vmware-tools doesn't come with DnD feature and had to install other vmware stuff: open-vm-tools and open-vm-tools-desktop

Comment: Did that clear up the mouse issue?  Open tools are for some guests.  If that is so, you may wish to find my answer at least helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try vmware pro -> edit -> preferences -> input -> tick grab keyboard and mouse input on mouse click also change below in cursor section optimise mouse for games: to automatic : from drop down list - worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here with Linux guest (Forgot why I turned from official tool, but "VM -> Reinstall VMware tools" option isn't even available). Open tools (Linux) works here (Also a lot of vmware guest stuff in guest kernel now) but mouse / keyboard focus gets trapped in guest (until ctrl-alt is pressed) [There is no problem on Windows guest, that I think is always using the official tool]
It's no problem grapping the mouse and keyboard from being focused when moving from host to guest. The moving to host again is a problem on Linux esp. on OpenRC environments (had it fixed but it installed some systemd and messed up some udev stuff and gave some serious problems. So I would say it's a linux-openrc/openvmtools problem that isn't very widely documented and gets a lot of false response.
I'm using VMware workstation 16.2.5. (Kernel 5.10.205 on both host and guest with separate options).

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Preferences -> Input -> Optimize mouse for games: Never

Neither VMware tools nor open tools solved the issue for me after downgrading from VMWare Workstation 17.5 to 17.0.2.

The setting even makes sense :)